# How to transfer folder security and permission from one folder to another (in 2 different servers)?

Tags: server, registry, file-permissions, windows-security, winreg

I am migrating my folder and files from one server to another. I was able to copy the security of the files using registory editor. But later when I manually added IIS_USRS for configuring my iis. All my folder security seems to have gone.
Copy pasting registory is no longer working. I tried deleting all folders and retrying but that also doesn't work.
Please suggest what can I try(I have more than 150 folders)

Tried Copying security registry again.
Tried deleting all the folders and recopied from source to destination.